# How to correctly escape XML special characters in an Rmarkdown document?

Tags: r, xml, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to render an Rmarkdown document which contains XML special characters, such as `<` and `>`.  If I leave them as plaintext, they get interpreted as XML and cause rendering to break.

I've tried escaping them like `&gt;` and `&lt;` but they just render as-are without converting into chevrons. I've also tried using a cdata section like `<![CDATA[>]]>` but that just renders like `]]>`.

How do I encode them so they render as normal chevrons `<` `>` ?

Comment: How about using \, i.e. `\<` and `\>` ?

Comment: I get ` Error in read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., as_html = as_html,  : 
  Name doi:10.1002 is not XML Namespace compliant [202]`

Comment: It worked here in my computer. What type of document are you rendering?

Comment: Rendering a .Rmd into a HTML

Comment: I couldn't use "\<" as that's an undefined escape sequence, so tried "\\<" which doesn't work

Comment: Could you try to render this? `---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---
Testing escape character: \< hi \>`

Comment: Ah I see the issue now - if I put `\<` directly into my .Rmd it would render fine, however I'm doing all the text arrangement in an R script which then gets passed as a parameter to the .Rmd. Normal R doesn't recognise `\<` so not sure how to get around this?

Comment: I tried rendering from script here and it also worked? I'll answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're rendering markdown from a script, you can start by using `'#` for comments that will be rendered into text. Then you can write markdown normally within that comment.

```
#' ---
#' title: "Test 2"
#' output: html_document
#' ---
#' 
#' \< Example sequence \>
0:10
```

I saved that as `test.R` and rendered:

```
rmarkdown::render("test.R")
```

Which looks like this:
[image: html_document]

Comment: I'm not so sure I can do this - I have a template `Report.Rmd`, and then in another script I'm doing

    input_text <- get_text()
    rmarkdown::render('Report.Rmd', params = list(input_text))

The template takes the parameter and inserts into its slot before rendering - at what stage can I swap out the `<` in `input_text` for `\<` without R complaining?

Comment: Is the `<` coming from the Report or your R script? You can try to make a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

We can just insert XML in Rmarkdown chunks and if we put it outside the R chunk, we get a list

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<note>  
  <to>Tove</to>  
  <from>Jani</from>  
  <heading>Reminder</heading>  
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>  
</note>  

# code 

```{}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<note>  
  <to>Tove</to>  
  <from>Jani</from>  
  <heading>Reminder</heading>  
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>  
</note>  

```
````

[image]